# How to process multiple record with same id into single record with login / logout time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[is this possible to make a "newtable" from "oldtable" like a picture down below?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7xAm.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use PIVOT method :


Declare @table table (id varchar(10),[time] time)
insert into @table
SELECT '01','10:08:23'
UNION ALL
SELECT '02','10:10:50'
UNION ALL
SELECT '01','13:30:00'

SELECT  *
FROM 
( 
   SELECT id , time , CASE WHEN MIN(RNo) = 1 THEN  'CheckIn' WHEN MAX(RNo) >  
   1 THEN  'CheckOut' END Type
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) RNo 
      FROM @table
   ) A 
   GROUP BY id , time 
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(time) FOR Type IN ([CheckIn],[CheckOut])
 )Pvt
```

Comment: is this only applied to that 3 records? i need it to automatically applied to all records on the table. thanks for reply..

Comment: @YasminYousaf,Its' for all records for your table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be use for matching column (s)

```
INSERT INTO `NEWTABLE`(`id`, `check in`) 
SELECT o.id, o.time FROM OLDTABLE o
```